# Reading CSV files from S3 in EC2 using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

In the current implementation, I have Java code which actually reads 2 or more CSV files, combines data based on business logic and saves data into a new CSV file. This java jar file is triggered in TIBCO by doing a directory watch i.e, when new set of files are placed this java code is triggered. 
All fine and working good, but due to AWS cloud the requirement is to host a EC2 instance and execute this java code but not use TIBCO to trigger instead build some java (like standalone/background process) application. 
Since I am not from Java background I am not sure on how to implement this standalone/background process which keeps a watch n S3 folder and trigger the process. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please be specific about which part of the problem is giving you difficulties.  If you show us the code you have written so far, it will help us to understand your problem.

Comment: There is actually no such thing as an "S3 folder". S3 is not a filesystem - it's a key/value store. Though many times the keys *look* like filesystem paths, the folders don't actually exist. You'll probably need to have a different mechanism. Read up about S3 and also about AWS lambdas, as they can be triggered by S3 events.

Comment: Apologies, thanks for the quick response, let me try to explain my requirement

Comment: 1. 2 to 4 CSV files will be uploaded to S3 bucket (to a specific folder eg. InputFiles)
2. Custom java code which actually reads these 2-4 csv files, apply some business logic and write the output to a new file and save it to (S3 bucket e.g., OutPutFiles) 
3. CSV file size could be around 200MB
4. In current on-prem implementation is taking around 12-14 mins to complete the process due to complex business logic. Since Lambda has a limitation of 15mins was thinking to have an EC2 instance and use some Java application that would read files for S3 bucket and save the output back to S3 bucket

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right architecture and also I am new to Java and hence was unsure if a Java background service application could be used in Ec2 to read CSV form S3.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your requirement is:

- Files are uploaded to Amazon S3
- This should trigger some code to process the files
- Then (presumably), store the resulting file back into Amazon S3

The best way to do this would be:

- Configure an **Amazon S3 Event** on the bucket to trigger an AWS Lambda function when a file is uploaded
- The Lambda function will be provided with the **Bucket Name and Key** (filename) of the new object
- The Lambda function can then **run your own code** to process the files, including downloading from/uploading to Amazon S3

The benefit of this method is that you do *not* require an Amazon EC2 instance. Instead, the Lambda function will trigger, execute and quit as a *serverless function*.

The Lambda function can be written in a variety of languages, such as Java, Python, .Net, Go, etc.

Take a look through the documentation and the samples.

See: [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)

One thing: I'm not sure what your code needs to do, but the Lambda function is triggered *for each file* that is uploaded. Therefore, if the goal is to combine several files into one file, you'll need to figure out what should trigger the job to start. This might involve ignoring certain files until the right one appears that will trigger the process.

Comment: Thanks John, 
1. CSV file size could be around 200MB and would require some complex business logic.

Comment: Since Lambda has a limitation of 15mins was thinking to have an EC2 instance and use some Java application that would read files for S3 bucket and save the output back to S3 bucket.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right approach of having the code executed in Ec2 instance

Comment: You can certainly do it on an EC2 instance. The biggest requirement is determining what "triggers" the job to run. You could use Lambda (triggered by S3, as above) to start the job on the EC2 instance (somehow). You then have the choice of either having the EC2 instance running continuously (good if there are jobs coming in through the day), or launching it only when wanted, then it can stop or terminate when the job is complete.